# Error after updating Gradle and plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, updates

I am using Android Studio and having problem running my Gradle after update Gradle version (2.10 to 3.3) and Android plugin version (2.1.2 to 2.3.2).

Please see the [error log file](https://pastebin.com/Mq2YbdMe).  Tried invalidate caches/restart, delete .gradle caches content, but doesn't help.
From my Gradle module,

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(prop1)
import com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser
```

`ConfigSlurper()` and `.builder` cannot be resolved. What is wrong with this update?

Answer (score 0):

hey please update your Android Sdk versions and then please restart your android studio